# Dash | Multiple H6() on the same line

Tags: html, python-3.x, plotly-dash

Goal: have two `H6()` on the same line.

I know to do this by having one `Row()` and two `Col()`. I am struggling to implement it ;(

Attempts:

```py
...
# H6('Line markers'),
# H6('Line colors'),
# H6('Line markers', 'Line colors')
Row(Col(Div([H6('Line markers')]))),
Row(Col(Div([H6('Line colors')]))),
#Row(Col(Div([H6('Line markers'), H6('Line colors')]))),
...
```

Webpage:

```
Line markers
Line colors
```

Desired Webpage:

```
Line markers                    Line colors
```

No error in runtime but just aesthetically annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
...
Row([Col(Div([H6('Line markers')])),
     Col(Div([H6('Line colors')]))]),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with flex box. Wrap both in a div with `style=dict(display='flex')`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to implement this ;( Could you provide full code, please?